# How to make a block only appear for a certain content type?

Tags: blocks

I have a content type and what I want to do is show a block on the right hand side only if the user is viewing that content type using a custom module. Any general pointers as to where I should start looking?

Comment: You are talking about only one content type?

Comment: Yes. It needs to be done programmatically and not using the ui. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a few ways.

If your content type always has a unique URL (such as /news) you can set the block to only show when on a page matching that URL.

Or this can be managed in a variety of ways using different plugins that allow for the manipulation of displaying content types and their corresponding views/blocks.

Are you currently using any plugins like that or have any themes installed?

Comment: No this is just assuming that I am using bartik theme. The url is the standard node/1 or node/2 etc etc. Any way we know programmatically if user is on certain content type?

Comment: @kratos once again, in a few ways. Each page has an automatically generated name when it is made that includes the content type, so you could reference the block by body.page-contentType .block and either display/hide it using JavaScript or CSS or really any way you prefer. You can see this name by inspecting the page using a browsers development tools.

Comment: @kratos did this work?